# What documents do Irish border control require?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, paperwork, ireland, turkish-citizens

I will travel to Ireland next week with my sister. I have a study visa and she has a tourist visa. What kind of documents will the police ask for? I have already submitted travel insurance to the embassy for a visa. However our travel dates have changed, will they want to see new travel insurance at the border? Do they need bank statements, and is there a minimum amount of money in my account I should show?

Comment: What citizenship(s) are involved? For clarity, by ‘tourist visa’ do you mean your sister actually has a visa or that she intends to enter visa-free by virtue of her citizenship?

Comment: We're both Turkish citizens and she has a tourism/visit short-stay visa and I have study long-stay visa. It will be our first time entering Ireland.

Comment: If you have an Irish Visa, that should generally be good enough since the embassy has already done the required background checks. That being said, it doesn't hurt to be through and bring more documentation in case. I'm a South African and I always travel with my insurance, bank accounts, letter of employment, proof of address (utility bill) and spare certified copies of my passport.

Answer (score 1):

It's very individual and really boils down to who's standing in front of you and how they perceive you.

They basically need to see you can support yourselves without resorting to (illegal) employment, and that your sister has incentive to return at the end of her stated duration of stay.

So your sister should bring bank statements along with a return ticket.